# How to parse nested information in JSON using jsonpath_ng

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, jsonparser, jsonpath-ng

I have the following JSON, which came from an API response:

```
{
    "expand": "names,schema",
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 50,
    "total": 3,
    "issues": [
        {
            "expand": "",
            "id": "10001",
            "self": "http://www.example.com/10001",
            "key": "ABC-1",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "From":"Ibiza",
                    "To":"Mallorca"
                },                
                {
                    "From":"Mallorca",
                    "To":"Miami"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "expand": "",
            "id": "10002",
            "self": "http://www.example.com/10002",
            "key": "ABC-2",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "From":"NYC",
                    "To":"Charlotte"
                },                
                {
                    "From":"Charlotte",
                    "To":"Los Angeles"
                },
                {
                    "From":"Los Angeles",
                    "To":"San Diego"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "expand": "",
            "id": "10003",
            "self": "http://www.example.com/10003",
            "key": "ABC-3",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "From":"Denver",
                    "To":"Boson"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Target**

My target would be to print in Python a list of combinations like:

```
10001 - Ibiza - Mallorca
10001 - Mallorca - Miami
10002 - NYC - Charlotte
10002 - Charlotte - Los Angeles
10002 - Los Angeles - San Diego
10003 - Denver - Boston
```

**What I have done**

The following snippet works fine, but I really can't understand how to merge the information. I understand that I should split the whole JSON into smaller parts, one for each item, and then apply the second and third catches...can anybody help me, please?

```
import jsonpath_ng.ext as jp
import json


data=json.loads(response.text)

# 1st catch: 10001,10002,10003
query = jp.parse("$.issues[*].id")
for match in query.find(data):
    key=match.value
    print(key)

#2nd catch: Ibiza, Mallorca, NYC, ...
query = jp.parse("$.issues[*].fields[*].From")
for match in query.find(data):
    key=match.value
    print(key)

#3nd catch: Mallorca, Miami, Charlotte, ...
query = jp.parse("$.issues[*].fields[*].To")
for match in query.find(data):
    key=match.value
    print(key)
```

Comment: Since your result requires data from multiple levels and nested lists, I'm wondering if it would not be easier to just walk the tree yourself rather than use `jsonpath_ng`. I don't know that package though so perhaps it has the ability to return multiple rows of a parent for each child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know that package, but I have used a similar one `jmespath`. Based on it, I might try:

```py
results = [
    f"{parent.value['id']} - {child.value['From']} -{child.value['To']}"
    for parent in jp.parse("$.issues[*]").find(data)
    for child in jp.parse("$.fields[*]").find(parent.value)
]

for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives me exactly what I was looking for!